How to Send Email When a JWT Token is Issued for a User in Keycloak
I have implemented a custom event listener in Keycloak that sends an email whenever a user logs in. Now, I want to change it so that it sends an email when a JWT token is issued to a user. Below is my current code:
public class CustomEventListenerProvider implements EventListenerProvider {

    private final KeycloakSession session;
    private final JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender;
....
public void onEvent(Event event) {
        if (EventType.LOGIN.equals(event.getType())) // I want to change this condition {
            String userId = event.getUserId();
            String email = session.users().getUserById(session.getContext().getRealm(), userId).getEmail();
            sendEmail(email);
        }
    }



private void sendEmail(String email) {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
    
        message.setTo(email);
        message.setSubject("JWT Issued");
        message.setText("A new JWT token has been issued for your account.");

        mailSender.send(message);
    }

I want to send an email when a JWT token is issued instead of when a user logs in, but I couldn't find a suitable event type. How can I achieve this? Which event should I listen to, and how should I modify my code?
I looked into the Keycloak documentation but couldn't find a clear example for this specific use case. I suspect that EventType.CODE_TO_TOKEN might be relevant, but I'm not sure how to implement it correctly.
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Take a look at the CODE_TO_TOKEN event. That EventType is used when an authentication code is exchanged for a token.
Listen for all events, catch CODE_TO_TOKEN and write an email based on that event.
